# Scrolling in SDL2, ie, changing integral coordinates of the giu's layout

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm trying to simulate 'scrolling' in an application in SDL2, however i dont think that moving each individual object on the screen every time the scroll event occurs is an efficient/elegant way of doing it. What i know of SDL2 is the top left begins at 0,0 in coordinates. For me to make this much easier to implement, is it possible to change the top left starting point of the GUI so that, when i scroll, it moves to say, 0,100 and next scroll, 0,200 etc. How could I do this? Thanks

Comment: I don't do a lot with graphics, but I do recall an approach here. With SDL, you can paint (for lack of better words) the complete display and then blit it to the screen. If I recall correctly, to create a scroll (like movie credits) you paint an image the width of the screen but as tall as needed (many times the display height) and save the total image. You then blit a screenfull of the saved image at a time increasing the offset each time to create the scrolling effect. That way you don't create each individual piece each time, you display different parts of the pre-created image.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than changing the x,y position of the object itself, or changing the reference co-ordinate of SDL (which cannot be done), you can instead create offset variables.

For example, create an SDL_Point called ViewPointOffset:

```
SDL_Point ViewPointOffset;
```

The best practice is to put this in your window class (if you have one), or even better, a Camera class that is a member of the window class.

Then, when you're drawing, just subtract the offset from the x and y co-ordinates that you're drawing:

```
void draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer, const SDL_Point ViewPointOffset, SDL_Texture* tex, const SDL_Rect* srcrect, const SDL_Rect* dstrect){
    SDL_Rect* drawrect;
    drawrect->w = dstrect->w;
    drawrect->h = dstrect->h;
    drawrect->x = dstrect->x - ViewPortOffset.x;
    drawrect->y = dstrect->y - ViewPortOffset.y;
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, tex, srcrect, drawrect);
}
```

You can either create a second function, or attach a boolean to the input of that function, to allow you to ignore the offset; what if you have a GUI button that you don't want the offset to apply to, etc?

https://github.com/Helliaca/SDL2-Game is a small open source game using a similar method. You can find this code in base.cpp/.h

Comment: I’m not sure I quite understand this, I can see the helpfulness of having a camera class or window class, but I’m not sure how I would do that. The way I currently have it structured is “main screen” and “other screen” for example and I have a static class that handles the screens so it’s always called and when I need one screen open I have a Boolean for it, I could definitely improve this. If I was to implement a camera class, how can I do this if each screen has x and y locations for each image and object on ththe screen? Because it seems as of now, I,d have to have an offset for each

Comment: Individual image, text rectangle etc.

Comment: @PeterWilson . The best practice is to give every individual thing you want to draw an SDL_Rect saying where it should be drawn and its size. With this, all you need to do is pass the above function the image (SDL_Texture), the location (SDL_Rect), and the stuff you already have and it'll draw it. Take some time to dissect and mess around with the GitHub game I posted (you can copy code from it directly into your own project, as it's public domain); it'll save you a lot of time.

Comment: okay, thank you that makes sense. If i was to have a camera class, would i have a static class accessed by every file that needs it and have a scroll value to add to each? For example, this might not be the best way, but i have a static event class, and i only call the method of Event_Handling() in my int main function, but i include the file in each other file that needs it and then access/change static variables of the event class within them? Sort of like this but with a camera class? Would that be a good way

Comment: @PeterWilson , you can pass the window (containing the camera class) to your event handler like so: `void Event_Handling(GameWindow* win)`, and changing the function that calls it to `Event_Handling(win)`, where you can act on it just like you would before it is passed along.

Comment: uh, perhaps i already have that, sorry im not sure what you mean. For my event file, it is static, i have 2 functions i call only once, in main file. 1, when initialising, i have my main window passed into my event class (which everything is static), and then i use that window for resizing the display after a window event. and then the event_handling, so i create a Window in the event class anyway, which i SDL_Destroy later. I'm just using that methodology as an example. As of now, when i scroll i have a static scrollOffset, it seems to work nicely but im wondering if its the best way for it?

Comment: the scroll offset is a static integer in the Event file which i use alot in my files (i include events.h in alot of files). Im not sure if this is how you meant i should do it?

Comment: @PeterWilson . I can't visualise your exact method, so I can't answer your question. If the method works, and you're happy with it, just go with it. If you keep your code modular (which having a window class will help do), it'll be easy to change if it causes problems later. Otherwise, I think you're overusing the static operator. If you've already defined a variable in the class definition (public, private, or protected) you don't need to use static. Part of making a program modular is to make it so it doesn't depend on the previous things you've put into it.

Comment: As of now, im happy with my static event class, however, im not sure then, how i can implement a window class that isnt static, because if i scroll down, i need an offset value, which applies to every aspect on the screen, so a static window class would have the same value that applies to all classes?

Comment: @PeterWilson if you're defining your window class in your main function and passing it to the individual functions that use it, you'll only have a single class of it.